# Publishing multiple instance of web role to different size VM

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I want to understand that while publishing a web role (having multiple instance) how can i publish web roles to different size of VM? Say, there are 3 instances of my web role. And using VS 2010 / 2012 with Azure SDK 2.0 i want to publish 1st instance on a small VM while remaining 2 on medium size VM. How can i do that using VS in a single publish attempt.

Comment: Simple answer: you can't do it. All the instances of a role must be of same size. Is there any particular reason why you would want to do that?

Comment: Hi Gaurav, Thanks for your revert. Yes, there is a use case where i might want to do it. For instance, i have got 3 instance of different size already. And they are hosting existing web roles and worker roles. 1st instance is a small size and 2 other are medium size and i know they are not utilized to max. hence, i don't want to buy another instance instead utilize the existing instances (but are of different size). Hence, the web role that i have should needs to be deployed to mix size VMs.

Comment: Since you're facing capacity utilization issues, as David recommended in his answer below you should look into `scaling out` your instances instead of `scaling up`. That will give you more flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gaurav said, it can't be done. A *role* defines the dimensions of the VM instances, so they're all equivalent. To get different size instances, you need to define multiple roles, each with specific VM sizes.

One thing to consider: If your app can run in a Small instance, then it should be possible to scale *out* to more instances as needed, then scale back *in* when those extra resources aren't needed. This should help you optimize your costs, especially when you scale down to only two instances (ok, you can scale down to one instance, but then there's no uptime SLA).

If, on the other hand, you really do need, say, Medium instances (maybe you have a specific memory requirement for your app), then that would be your common size and, again, scale out as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the revert.....so in that case - i will have to do multiple deployments for each web role (by selecting relevant web role from the subscription file) and publish the web app. 3 times if i have to deploy on existing 3 different (existing) web roles.

Comment: I'm still not seeing why you'd need to do that, if your app runs in a Small (and simply scale out to meet demands). That said: Instead of multiple deployments, you can create multiple web roles within a single deployment, each with a different size, and change the instance count accordingly. Just remember: An IP address (and related domain name) is tied to one deployment. If you push your web role to multiple deployments, you'll now have multiple URLs / IP addresses, and you'll need to direct traffic across all of these URLs accordingly.